# How can I grap resident set size from Python on Solaris?

Tags: python, solaris, getrusage

Calling resource.getrusage() from Python returns a 0 value for resident set size on Solaris and Linux systems. On Linux you can pull the RSS From /proc//status instead. Does anybody have a good way to pull RSS on Solaris, either similar or not to the Linux workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Solaris's `psinfo` under `/proc`? ([solaris proc(4) docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0633/6j9vn6q6d/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

Well...you can pull it from the pmap application by calling pmap -x. But I was looking  more for a way to access the info directly in /proc from my app. The only way to do it is to access the /proc/<pid>/xmap file. Unfortunately, the data is stored as an array of prxmap structs...so either a Python C-module is in order or using the ctypes module. I'll post an update when I get one of those written.